# java - determine if a date is binary

Tags: java, date, binary

I have a program that calculates whether or not a date entered by a user is a leap year or not. I think I got that all down but I also need to see if the date that is entered is a binary date (i.e. 1/1/11. I'm not really sure the best way to go about this, maybe an charAt reference? Any help would be must appreciated!

```
//****************************
import java.util.Scanner;

public class leapYearCalc {
private int day = 0;
private int month = 0;
private int year = 0;
Scanner myScan = new Scanner (System.in);


//---------------------------------
//Constructor to accept and initialize instance data
//---------------------------------
public leapYearCalc(int day, int month, int year){
this.day=day;
this.month=month;
this.year=year;
}

//--------------------------------
//Get day
//--------------------------------
public int getDay(){
    System.out.println("Whats the day?");
    day = myScan.nextInt();
    return day;
}

//--------------------------------
//Get day
//--------------------------------
public int getMonth(){
    System.out.println("Whats the month in numerical form?");
    month = myScan.nextInt();
    return month;
}

//--------------------------------
//Get day
//--------------------------------
public int getYear(){
    System.out.println("Whats the year (i.e. 2004)?");
    year = myScan.nextInt();
        if (year<1582)
            System.out.println("Please enter a value above 1582");
    return year;
}


//--------------------------------
 //1. If a year is divisible by 4 it is a leap year if 2 does not apply.
 //2. If a year is divisible by 100 it is not a leap year unless #3 applies.
 //3. If a year is divisible by 400 it is a leap year.
//--------------------------------
//Calculate leap year   
public String toString() {
        if (year % 4 == 0) {
            if (year % 100 != 0) {
            System.out.println(year + " is a leap year.");
            }
            else if (year % 400 == 0) {
            System.out.println(year + " is a leap year.");
            }
            else {
            System.out.println(year + " is not a leap year.");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(year + " is not a leap year.");
        }
        return null;
    }

    //--------------------------------
    //Check to see if date is binary
    //--------------------------------
    public int getBinary(){
        while(month == 01 || month == 10)

            if(day == 01 || day == 10 && year == 00 || year == 01)
                System.out.println("It's a binary date!");
        System.out.println("It's not a binary date");
        return month;

    }
}
```

Comment: How hard can it be to see if all the digits are a 0 or 1?

Comment: if this is homework then you should add the homework tag to it

Comment: oohh, I didn't know there was a homework tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are checking if the day, month and year fields are either 1, 10 0r 11. If they are then it is a binary date, otherwise it is not a binary date. Maybe your getBinary() method should simply return a boolean value. You do not need a while loop there, rather an if statement would work:

```
public boolean getBinary(){
    if(month == 1 || month == 10 || month == 11){
        if(day == 1 || day == 10 || day = 11){
              if(year == 0 || year == 1 || year == 10 || year == 11){
                 return true;
              }

     }
     return false;
}
```

In addition your leap year calculation can be simplified if you start with the divisible by 400. e.g.

```
  if(year is divisible by 400)
      leap year
  else
      if year is divisible by 100 then
         not a leap year
      else
           if year is divisble by 4 then
              leap year
           else
              not a leap year
```

or it can all be made into a simple boolean expression like this

```
 if(year is divisible by 400 or (year is not divisble by 100 and divisible by 4))
        leap year
 else
        not leap year
```

===================
Considering a four digit year then you could split each digit off like this:

```
     int num = year; //to preserve the original year value
     int digit = num / 1000; //get first digit
     //check if digit is 0 or 1
     num = num % 1000; //remove first digit
     digit = num / 100; //get second digit
     //check if digit is 0 or 1
     num = num % 100;//remove second digit
     etc
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent! How much more complicated would it make it if the user were to enter in the whole year i.e. 2001?

Answer (score 2):

As it is a homework, I will only give you hints:
I bet what you mean by "binary date" is the year, month and day is composed of "1" and "0" only?

Here are the hints:

1. Convert the provided Date to String, using SimpleDateFormat.  The result should contains only 8 characters: 4 for year, 2 for month and 2 for day
2. Check the result String to see if it contains all 0 or 1.  You can use a for loop to check each character to see if they are '0' or '1', or you can simply use regular expression to check against the pattern "^[01]+$"

Answer (score 0):

Ok I might be too late but the best way to do this would be by a using a regex

```
   public boolean getBinary(){
        String str = day+""+month+"year";
        return str.matches("[01]+");

    }
```